# How to parse a YAML file with Java/Jackson and manage $ref reference values

Tags: java, jackson, yaml

I am parsing a YAML file that contains $ref properties using Jackson in Java:

```
servers:
  server1:
    name: EU server
    host:
      $ref: '#/definitions/host'
  server2:
    name: USA server
    host:
      $ref: '#/definitions/host'

definitions:
  host:
    ip: 10.0.0.1
    port: 9999
```

Code:

```
    String content = ...;

    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory());
    objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);

    Servers servers = objectMapper.readValue(content, Servers.class);
```

How can I configure Jackson to follow the $ref properties ?

Edit: The resulting object would have servers.server1.host.ip and servers.server1.host.port properties available instead of the $ref property.

Comment: You can refer to this implementation https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-parser, which is specific to swagger, however, there is RefProcessor to follow ref object.

Answer (score 1):

`$ref` in YAML is just a scalar, it does not have any special meaning. You are probably using a tool that assigns a special meaning to it, but you don't tell us which one.

Jackson is able to load YAML, but does not have builtin support for application-specific schemas (a schema in YAML is what assigns special properties to a scalar like `$ref`). This means that if you want to interpret `$ref` according to the semantics of whatever tool you're using, you need to implement it yourself or use the API of that tool if possible.

If you assumed that `$ref` is a YAML feature (it is not), have a look at anchors and aliases which are the YAML way of referencing a previously defined node:

```
foo: &bar original  # scalar `original` with anchor
bar: *bar           # reference to scalar `original`
```

Comment: I assume that $ref are not YAML. I am looking for a library that handles the references after reading the file.

Comment: You have to go into more detail then. What should `$ref` do? In your example, the path (I assume it is one) you give for your `$ref`s does not even exist.

Answer (score 0):

You may couple SnakeYAML and Jackson. SnakeYAML is embedded in Jackson (and is used internally by it), so you already have access to it.

Convert first the YAML string to Map (the aliases are resolved):

```
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml;

Yaml yaml = new Yaml();
Map<String, Object> obj = yaml.load(<yamlStr>);
```

Then, use Jackson to serialize it to your model:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
MyModel model = mapper.convertValue(obj, MyModel.class);
```

Comment: The SnakeYAML parser does not follow the $ref references. Not a valid answer.

Comment: Sorry, you are right, I misread the thread - I thought that the poster was speaking of the Yaml aliases (&XXX and *XXX)